# Rstudio's console stuck while interactive mode testing

Tags: r, rstudio, interactive

I try to test an interactive mode in Rstudio:

```
ans <- readLines("stdin", n = 1)
print(ans)
```

However the console gets stuck and not accepting any commands. I cannot even quit this mode after that and have to reboot the entire Rstudio.
What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read from `stdin()`, not `file("stdin")`:

```r
ans <- readLines(stdin(), n = 1)
```

From `?stdin`:

> `stdin()` refers to the 'console' and not to the C-level `stdin` of the process.  The distinction matters in GUI consoles (which may not have an active `stdin`, and if they do it may not be connected to console input), and also in embedded applications. If you want access to the C-level file stream `stdin`, use `file("stdin")`.

Comment: That works within Rstudio but not for the terminal or cmd.exe outside the Rstudio. (in the last case, the console doesn't wait an input from an user). Is there any compromise for testing the code within and outside the Rstudio?

Comment: On macOS, `stdin()` works as expected when running R from Terminal. I am slightly surprised that you see different behaviour on Windows. I guess you can try `ans <- readLines(if (Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO") == "1") stdin() else "stdin", n = 1)` ...

Comment: This works, finally.
P.S: I checked it and on Linux it behaved just like on Windows. Thank you!